# Data inside a LIst<String[]> dissappears (UWP)

Tags: c#, string, list, uwp, null

the situation is the following:
On Page one i have a button that leads to page two and transports itself as an object to that site.
On page 2 i can set a few things that are stored in a `List<string[]>` that list is now moved by calling a method on Page one that sets the List on that page. and then i return to page one.
Everything is set and the data was received.
Now as soon as i try to access that data it gets null. I have no statement anywhere in the code that could set it to null. I only have to references:
1.

```
public void setMaterialData(List<string[]> data )
        {
            MaterialData = data;
        }
```

and 2.

```
dataObject.materialdata = MaterialData;
```

and i already checked if the constructor is called again and overwrites it, but it doesn't. And strangely that happens with nothing else in my code so far.

Things that might be important:
I have the cache mode set to enabled,
I noticed that the constructor of the Window is called when i navigate away from page one to page two and i don't know why?(there is no reference to my list in there though)

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with UWP so I don't feel to confident but: Are you sure that the object you're setting the materialData to is the same object as the one initialized from page2 ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that but i'll try to answer: From page two i set ```data``` into ```MaterialData``` and then i want to put that data into an object that carries many different types of data (```dataObject```) for further processing. But my data gets lost somewhere between there. And i transfer the data from page two to page one with the method ```setMaterialData(List<string[]> data )```. does that answer the question? Thank you

Comment: Hello @JL_Funk, According to the code you provided, it seems that `MaterialData` is a variable that can be accessed by both Page1 and Page2. How is it defined? Can you provide more complete code, including navigation method, etc., which will help us further analyze your problem.

Answer (score 0):

- if you are not caching page then the newly navigated page is a new instance of the page and that maybe one possibility of getting field and property to Null
- another possibility is resetting the variable as the page loads because every time the
  page comes up to display it fires up page_loaded event if you are using that for initializing variable and other components than that may reset them to null
- can you can check and confirm that if the navigated page is the same as the saved instance simply  by checking (savedObj == this)